# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am getting this error in this line: $("#register-form").validate. Can someone help me?
Also, if I write this script how should I call it in the form? Or will it work without calling it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($, W, D) {
           var JQUERY4U = {};
            JQUERY4U.UTIL = {
                    setupFormValidation : function() {
            //form validation rules
                $("#register-form").validate({
                rules : {
                    name : "required",
                    email : "required",
                    phone : "required"

                },
                messages : {
                    name : "Please enter your name",
                    email : "Please enter your email",
                    phone : "Please enter your phone"

                },
                submitHandler : function(form) {
                    if ($("#id").val() == "")
                        createRegistration();
                    else
                        alert("Error loading the data");
                }
            });
        }
    };

    //when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
    $(D).ready(function($) {
        JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
    });

})(jQuery, window, document);</script>
```

Comment: It seems like you haven't loaded the validation plugin.

Comment: Did you include the **validate.js** file? Please post other script tags as well, where you include js files.

Comment: I only added this <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>

Comment: You need to include this plugin `<script src="/pathtoplugin/jquery.validate.js"></script>`

Comment: Thank you. But the error is still there.

Comment: the path u gave is not correct...it shows error there as well...

Comment: Use `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js` as plugin url

Comment: Thank you, Satpal.
How should I call the script in my form? I am doing it for the first time so totally clueless.

Comment: Can anyone check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978847/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's improve your code and use **[a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/5jL5D/)** to help you a little more:

```
$(function(){
    jquery4u.util.setupFormValidation();
});

var jquery4u = {
    util: {
        setupFormValidation: function(){
            $("#register-form").validate({
                rules : {
                    name : "required",
                    email : "required",
                    phone : "required"
                },
                messages : {
                    name : "Please enter your name",
                    email : "Please enter your email",
                    phone : "Please enter your phone"
                },
                submitHandler : function(form) {
                    if ($("#id").val() == "")
                        createRegistration();
                    else
                        alert("Error loading the data");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```