# uncaught typeerror undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-plugins

I am new to JQuery and doesn't know how to handle errors like uncaught `TypeError: undefined is not a function`. I don't know how to put the jQuery code below in order. Can someone please arrange it in order....

```
@model Mvc4_WebGrid_CRUD.Models.PagedCustomerModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "WebGrid CRUD Operations";
WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize);
grid.Bind(Model.Customer,
          autoSortAndPage: false,
          rowCount: Model.TotalRows
); 
}   
    <style type="text/css">
    #grid {
    clear: both;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #c7c5c7;
}
    #grid thead, #grid tfoot td {
        text-align: left;
        font-weight: bold;
        height: 35px;
        color: #000;
        background-color: #d2d0d2;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    }

    #grid td {
        padding: 4px 6px 0px 4px;
        vertical-align: top;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    }

input {
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 2px 0 2px 0px;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 170px;
}
 </style>   
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
//Here is where I get the error
    $("#results").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Title',
    draggable: false,
    width: 500,
    height: 400,
    model: true,
    success: function () {
        alert('working fine');
    }
});
});
function openPopup() {
    $("#results").dialog("open");
}
</script>
```

The below code works fine

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".add").live("click", function () {
    var existrow = $('.save').length;
    if (existrow == 0) {
        var index = $("#grid tbody tr").length + 1;
        var Name = "Name_" + index;
        var Address = "Address_" + index;
        var ContactNo = "ContactNo_" + index;
        var Save = "Save_" + index;
        var Cancel = "Cancel_" + index;
        var tr = '<tr class="alternate-row"><td></td><td><span> <input id="' + Name + '" type="text" /></span></td>' +
             '<td><span> <input id="' + Address + '" type="text" /></span></td>' +
             '<td><span> <input id="' + ContactNo + '" type="text" /></span></td>' +
             '<td> <a href="#" id="' + Save + '" class="save">Save</a><a href="#" id="' + Cancel + '"  class="icancel">Cancel</a></td>' +
         '</tr>';

        $("#grid tbody").append(tr);
    }
    else {
        alert('First Save your previous record !!');
    }
});
$(".icancel").live("click", function () {
    var flag = confirm('Are you sure to cancel');
    if (flag) {
        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
    }
});
$(".save").live("click", function () {
    var id = $("#grid tbody tr").length;
    var Name = $("#Name_" + id).val();
    var Address = $("#Address_" + id).val();
    var ContactNo = $("#ContactNo_" + id).val();

    if (id != "") {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveRecord", "Home")',
            data: { "name": Name, "address": Address, "contactno": ContactNo },
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function () { },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.result == true) {
                    $("#divmsg").html("Record has been saved successfully !!");
                    setTimeout(function () { window.location.replace("WebGridCRUD"); }, 2000);
                }
                else {
                    alert('There is some error');

                }

            }

        });
    }
});
$(".edit").live("click", function () {
    var str = $(this).attr("id").split("_");
    id = str[1];
    var Name = "#Name_" + id;
    var spanName = "#spanName_" + id;
    var Address = "#Address_" + id;
    var spanAddress = "#spanAddress_" + id;
    var ContactNo = "#ContactNo_" + id;
    var spanContactNo = "#spanContactNo_" + id;
    $(Name).show();
    $(spanName).hide();
    $(Address).show();
    $(spanAddress).hide();
    $(ContactNo).show();
    $(spanContactNo).hide();
    $(this).hide();
    $("#Update_" + id).show();
    $("#Cancel_" + id).show();
});
$(".cancel").live("click", function () {
    var str = $(this).attr("id").split("_");
    id = str[1];
    var Name = "#Name_" + id;
    var spanName = "#spanName_" + id;
    var Address = "#Address_" + id;
    var spanAddress = "#spanAddress_" + id;
    var ContactNo = "#ContactNo_" + id;
    var spanContactNo = "#spanContactNo_" + id;

    $(Name).hide();
    $(spanName).show();
    $(Address).hide();
    $(spanAddress).show();
    $(ContactNo).hide();
    $(spanContactNo).show();

    $(this).hide();
    $("#Update_" + id).hide();

    $("#Edit_" + id).show();
});

$(".update").live("click", function () {
    var str = $(this).attr("id").split("_");
    id = str[1];

    var Name = $("#Name_" + id).val();
    var spanName = $("#spanName_" + id).val();
    var Address = $("#Address_" + id).val();
    var spanAddress = $("#spanAddress_" + id).val();
    var ContactNo = $("#ContactNo_" + id).val();
    var spanContactNo = $("#spanContactNo_" + id).val();
    if (id != "") {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateRecord", "Home")',
            data: { "id": id, "name": Name, "address": Address, "contactno": ContactNo },
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function () {//alert(id);
            },
            success: function (data) {

                if (data.result == true) {
                    $("#Update_" + id).hide();
                    $("#Cancel_" + id).hide();
                    $("#Edit_" + id).show();

                    var Name = "#Name_" + id;
                    var spanName = "#spanName_" + id;
                    var Address = "#Address_" + id;
                    var spanAddress = "#spanAddress_" + id;
                    var ContactNo = "#ContactNo_" + id;
                    var spanContactNo = "#spanContactNo_" + id;

                    $(Name).hide();
                    $(spanName).show();
                    $(Address).hide();
                    $(spanAddress).show();
                    $(ContactNo).hide();
                    $(spanContactNo).show();

                    $(spanName).text($(Name).val());
                    $(spanAddress).text($(Address).val());
                    $(spanContactNo).text($(ContactNo).val());
                }
                else {
                    alert('There is some error');
                }
            }

        });
    }
});

$(".delete").live("click", function () {
    var str = $(this).attr("id").split("_");
    id = str[1];

    var flag = confirm('Are you sure to delete ??');
    if (id != "" && flag) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: '@Url.Action("DeleteRecord", "Home")',
            data: { "id": id },
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function () { },
            success: function (data) {

                if (data.result == true) {
                    $("#Update_" + id).parents("tr").remove();
                }
                else {
                    alert('There is some error');
                }
            }

        });
    }
});
</script>
<div id="divmsg" style="color: green; font-weight: bold"></div>
<a href="#" class="add">Add New</a>
<br />
<br />
@grid.GetHtml(
htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" },
fillEmptyRows: false,
mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
firstText: "<< First",
previousText: "< Prev",
nextText: "Next >",
lastText: "Last >>",
 columns: new[] {

    grid.Column("CustID", 
                header: "ID", canSort: false),
    grid.Column(header: "Name",format: @<span> <span id="spanName_@item.CustID">@item.Name</span> @Html.TextBox("Name_"+(int)item.CustID,(string)item.Name,new{@style="display:none"})</span>),
    grid.Column(header: "Address",format: @<span> <span id="spanAddress_@item.CustID">@item.Address</span> @Html.TextBox("Address_"+(int)item.CustID,(string)item.Address,new{@style="display:none"})</span>),
    grid.Column(header: "Contact No",format: @<span> <span id="spanContactNo_@item.CustID">@item.ContactNo</span> @Html.TextBox("ContactNo_"+(int)item.CustID,(string)item.ContactNo,new{@style="display:none"})</span>),
    grid.Column(header: "Action",format:@<text>
<a href="#" id="Edit_@item.CustID" class="edit">Edit</a>
<a href="#" id="Update_@item.CustID" style="display:none" class="update">Update</a>
<a href="#" id="Cancel_@item.CustID" style="display:none"  class="cancel">Cancel</a>
<a href="#" id="Delete_@item.CustID"  class="delete">Delete</a>
<a href="#" id="Details_@item.CustID" class="details">Details</a>
@Ajax.ActionLink("Ajax Link","AjaxView",new{Id=@item.CustID},new AjaxOptions    { HttpMethod="GET",UpdateTargetId="results",
 InsertionMode= InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess="openPopup"})

<div id="dialog-detail" style="display: none">
</div>

</text>)
})
<div class="dialog"></div>
<div class="results" style="display:none;"></div>
```

I just get the error when I try to open the dialog box in above code. I can find Uncaught error. Might be because of the jQuery is not in order rest all it is fine. Can anyone put the above in order. Many thanks

Comment: Do you have a final html or something that I can look at? Maybe your selector '#results' is looking for the `<div id="results">` while you have `<div class="results">`. try and  use the '.resutls' selector.

Comment: @VeldMuijz thanks for your reply I did that but still doesn't works same error within chrome console. Can u plz tell me the order of jquery is appropriate or not. Thanks

Comment: First things first: if you put your script in a separate JS file and link to it, not put client-side script code directly into the page/view, the Visual Studio debugger will work for Javascript too.

Comment: Also, update to jQuery 1.11.1 if you can and move to using delegated `on`  events instead of using `live`.

Answer (score 0):

You have one obvious issue that may cause problems. Your HTML has a div with `class="results"`, but your selector says `#results` (i.e. find an element with `id="results"`)

You *could* change the selector to `.results` (as @VeldMuijz suggested in comment), *but* you also have an Ajax `ActionLink` which requires an id as it specifies `UpdateTargetId="results"`

Instead add the id to your results div.

e.g. change this:

```
<div class="results" style="display:none;"></div>
```

to this:

```
<div id="results" style="display:none;"></div>
```

I also recommend with MVC projects that you put your JS code in separate JS files. Visual Studio can't debug both Razor and Javascript in the same view, but it can if the script is in its own file.